# React.render() throws "ReactDOM is not defined" when using React

Tags: reactjs

After executing `npm install -g create-react-app`, the project folder was created with `create-react-app ./example`.

We used `npm start` in the later project to run in developer mode.

The following simple example of *App.js* should output 'Hello World', but a compilation error occurs:

```
ReactDOM.render(s
  <H1>Hello, World!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The error is as follows:

> Failed to Compile - ./src/App.js ReactDOM is not defined

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is an `s` after `render(`. `</h1>` should be `</H1>`

Answer (score 5):

> - Remove the "s" after render
> - add the modules of react adn react-dom

```
import React from 'react'

import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
```

> - check tag h1 name

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 
  adding "import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';" at the top.
It will be run.